# Getopts option to echo only when a function has been executed

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am creating a command called "remove" that basically functions the same way as the rm command but instead of actually deleting files, it stores them into a recycle bin folder.

I am working on the options for the "remove" command and having some difficulties with the -v option. The -v option is supposed to have the same functionality as it would with the rm command; it echoes a message that says that the file has been deleted.

My script looks like this:

```
flag=0


mainprocess(){

for filename in $*

mv $filename ~/deleted/$(basename $filename)"_"$(stat -c%i $filename)
flag=1

done
```

The getopts section of the script looks like this

```
while getopts v opt
do
shift
case $opt in

v)
for file in $*
do
if [ $flag -eq 1 ] 
then
echo "The file $file has been deleted" 
fi
done
 ;;
esac

if [ $flag -eq 0 ]
then
mainprocess $*
fi
```

My approach to the -v option was that once the mainprocess function was run, it would set the flag variable to 1 then it would echo the message that the file had been deleted.
Whenever i run the command however with the -v option, the "file has been deleted" message is never echoed. i tried displaying the value of the flag variable aswell and it was always 0 even if i run the mainprocess command.

Comment: You should double-quote your variable references (except ‘$VERBOSE‘, if you use wef’ Suggestion), and use ‘“$@“‘ instead of ‘$*‘. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding code to tell the user what is being done, just use the -v option of mv itself. Something like this:

```
VERBOSE=
while getopts v opt
do
    shift
    case $opt in

        v) VERBOSE=-v ;;
    esac
done

for filename in $*
do
    mv $VERBOSE $filename '~/deleted/$(basename $filename)"_"$(stat -c%i $filename)'
done
```